# Passing the Eventlistener to the correct function in JS

Tags: javascript, html, function, addeventlistener

I have two buttons (each of them has a value which matches the id of a dish in the food menu) with two EventListeners. One button for adding something to a shopping cart and one button to remove something from the shopping cart. My problem is, that i cant figure out how to pass the Eventlistener to the correct class function. This is my code so far:

```
class Cart {
    
    constructor() {
        this.inhalt = [];
    }

    add(item) {
        this.inhalt.push(item);
        console.log(this.inhalt)
    }

    remove(item) {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.inhalt.length; i++) {
            if (this.inhalt[i].id === item.id) {
                this.inhalt.splice(i, 1);
                console.log(this.inhalt)
            }
        }
    }

    sum() {
        let s = null;
        this.inhalt.price.forEach(element => {
            s += element
        });
        console.log(s)
    }
}

const myCart = new Cart();

function getItem(type) {
    let item = null;
        for (let i=0; i<speisekarte.length; i++) {
            if (speisekarte[i].id === this.value) {
                item = speisekarte[i];
                break;
            }
        }
        if (type == "plus") {myCart.add(item)}
        else if (type == "minus") {myCart.remove(item)};
}

let plus = document.querySelectorAll(".kaufen");   
plus.forEach(el =>{                             
    let type = "plus"; el.addEventListener("click", getItem(type));
});

let minus = document.querySelectorAll(".zurück");
minus.forEach(el =>{
    let type = "minus"; el.addEventListener("click", getItem(type));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be calling the functions when registering the event listeners.

Instead of:

```
let plus = document.querySelectorAll(".kaufen");   
plus.forEach(el =>{                             
    let type = "plus"; el.addEventListener("click", getItem(type));
});

let minus = document.querySelectorAll(".zurück");
minus.forEach(el =>{
    let type = "minus"; el.addEventListener("click", getItem(type));
});
```

Do this:

```
let plus = document.querySelectorAll(".kaufen");   
plus.forEach(el =>{                             
    el.addEventListener("click", () => getItem("plus"));
});

let minus = document.querySelectorAll(".zurück");
minus.forEach(el =>{
    el.addEventListener("click", () => getItem("minus"));
});
```